# add output to a new csv line using a linux terminal

Tags: shell, csv, terminal

I want to add the output of the following terminal command to a new row in the one CSV file. The following command adds the correct data to the following columns.

```
((date +%Y-%m-%d); cat file.txt | wc -l) | tr '\n' ',' >> output.csv
```

Current output

```
Row1: date | number | next date | text number | etc | etc
```

Desired output

```
Row 1: date | number
Row 2: date | number
Row 3: etc | etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Portable:

```
(( date +%Y-%m-%d; cat file.txt | wc -l) | tr '\n' ','; echo) >> output.csv
```

or using builtin in some shells but also available externally in coreutils package *printf* command:

```sh
printf "%s, %d,\n" "$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" "$(cat file.txt | wc -l)" >> output.csv
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding echo gave me what I wanted.